# Loop function for reading csv files and store them in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop

I have a folder in which are stored approximately 10 subfolders, containing 4 .csv files each! Each subfolder corresponds to a weather station, and each file in each subfolder contain temperature data for different period
*(e.g. station134_2000_2005.csv,station134_2006_2011.csv,station134_2012_2018.csv etc.)* .

I wrote a loop for opening each folder, and rbind all data in one data frame but it is not very handy to do my work.

I need to create a loop so that those 4 files from each subfolder, rbined together to a dataframe, and then stored in a different "slot" in a list, or if it's easier,each station rbined csv data (namely each subfolder) to be exported from the loop as dataframe.

The code I wrote, which opens all files in all folders and create a big (rbined) data frame is:

```
directory <- list.files()   # to have the names of each subfolder
stations <- data.frame()    # to store all the rbined csv files

library(plyr)


for(i in directory){
  periexomena <- list.files(i,full.names = T, pattern = "\\.csv$")
  for(f in periexomena){
    data_files <- read.csv(f, stringsAsFactors = F, sep = ";", dec = ",")
    stations <- rbind.fill(data_files,stations)
  }
```

Does anyone knows how can **I have a list with each subfolder's rbined 4 csv files data** in different slot, or how can I *modify the abovementioned code* in order to export in different data frame, the data from each subfolder?

Comment: Don't `rbind` on each iteration, it scales horribly (read [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), chapter 2 *Growing Objects*). Instead, `alldat <- lapply(directory, read.csv2, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` should be a good start, then `do.call(rbind.fill, alldat)`.

Comment: ... but that doesn't address your "slot" portion ...

Comment: Thank you for this interesting read. I tried to apply this knowledge in order to achieve my goal, but I haven't succeed yet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```r
slotted <- lapply(setNames(nm = directory), function(D) {
  alldat <- lapply(list.files(D, pattern="\\.csv$", full.names=TRUE),
                   function(fn) {
                     message(fn)
                     read.csv2(fn, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
                   })
  # stringsAsFactors=F should be the default as of R-3.6, I believe
  do.call(rbind.fill, alldat)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it, but I got the following error: 
*Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input*

Comment: Oops, typo, changed `dir` to `D` in the inner `lapply`. Try again please!

Comment: Hi again! I'd located the typo and I had corrected it, sorry I should have mention it. That was not the problem, the error message remains the same. Maybe it would help if I sent the last couple of traceback steps: 6. stop("no lines available in input") 5. read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, fill = fill, comment.char = comment.char, ...) 4.FUN(X[[i]], ...) –

Comment: I can't help with that. In a shell, I dir `mkdir ~/tmp/tmp1 ~/tmp/tmp2`, then saved a few rows of `mtcars` into `"~/tmp/tmp1/mt1.csv"` and more into other similar files, set `directory <- list.files("~/tmp", full.names=TRUE)`, then ran the code in this answer, and it worked. Directories without `.csv` files do not break it. Entries in `"~/tmp/"` that are not directories do not break it. If you're having problems, then I suggest you find the specific file that is causing that error and fix that. I just edited in a `message` that will tell you more specific when that occurs. Check that file.

Comment: You are absolutely right! One of all those *csv* files was empty and was the reason why it didn't work. 

Thank you very much, not only for your patience and perseverance in finding the cause of the error, but also because through your answer I learned how to recognize such errors and deal with them myself.